# mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 8 (Psych::SyntaxError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm learning RoR by The Ruby on Rails Tutorial (Michael Hartl).

When I add to .gemrc

```
sublime ~/.gemrc
```

(Sublime Text is installed) and I just check, for example

```
gem -v
```

I get

```
Failed to load /home/gvyntyk/.gemrc because it doesn't contain valid YAML hash
```

BTW:

```
gvyntyk@gvyntyk-r60:~$ ldconfig -p | grep libyaml
libyaml-0.so.2 (libc6) => /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libyaml-0.so.2
```

And when I add to .gemrc lines:

```
install: --no-rdoc --no-ri
update:  --no-rdoc --no-ri
```

(Of course, I don't want to install docs)

I get error:

```
gvyntyk@gvyntyk-r60:~$ gem install rails --version 4.0.2
/home/gvyntyk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 8 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /home/gvyntyk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
    from /home/gvyntyk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
    from /home/gvyntyk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
    from /home/gvyntyk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:332:in `load_file'
    from /home/gvyntyk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:197:in `initialize'
    from /home/gvyntyk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `new'
    from /home/gvyntyk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `do_configuration'
    from /home/gvyntyk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in `run'
    from /home/gvyntyk/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

When I delete `.gemrc`, I don't have those troubles and I can install Rails.

What's wrong?

Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Comment: Just remove a space before `update` in your `.gemrc` file.

Comment: The space is only in this page, in .gemrc the space missing.

Comment: So, why do you have not valid YAML? Try to lint content of your file somewhere, for example there: http://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: Copy content of file and paste it there. Press "Go"

Comment: I don't know which YAML-file is wanted. If it ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib-ruby/2.0.0/yaml.rb then I get: yntax error on line 16, col 2:' class EngineManager $:nodoc:'

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing what all the previous comments said, I also had this problem and it is a syntax issue with a .yml so I would suggest checking your code in any of the yaml checking web pages or try to play with it and see what solves your problem.

In my case my error was in my sidekiq.yml:

```
:verbose: true
  :concurrency: 25
  :queues:
    - [mailers, 7]
    - [default, 5]
```

Solution:

```
:concurrency: 25
:queues:
  - [mailers, 7]
  - [default, 5]
```

By the way for free heroku plans you should use:

```
:concurrency: 1
:queues:
  - [mailers, 7]
  - [default, 5]
```

Found that after many alerts from Heroku went up, any way have a great day!